# 3-vote close - how's it going?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

### UPDATE: While the testing period has ended, this change has been well-received by the community so we have opted to not reset the votes needed to close/reopen to 5 while we look at data.

Please let me know if you have any concerns about this change in the planned process or if you feel the number of votes should be changed back at least temporarily. I'll be back in a few weeks with the results of the project.

---

Part of understanding the impact of three-vote closure is to understand what impact it's having on y'all. I'd like to ask anyone who feels up to it to **write an answer to this question** and to tell us about your experience over the past few weeks.

The sorts of things I'm interested in knowing (feel free to address all or none or add your own) -

- Did this help?
- Did it hurt?
- Did it make you more interested in close/reopen reviewing? Less?

  - Are there things other than 3-vote close impacting your interest in reviewing?
- If you can't vote but do flag, did this make you more/less likely to flag?
- Would you prefer to go back to 5?
- Should it be permanent?
- What would you like me to look into when it comes to analyzing the data from the test?
- Were there any side-effects (good or bad) that you want me to be aware of?

These are merely prompts, so feel free to add anything I'm missing that you think is worth saying. This is focused on how you're feeling about it and what data you want me to look at, so don't feel like you need to analyze the data over the last 30 days - though you're welcome to if that's how you figure out what you feel.

If you have any outstanding questions, also feel welcome to ask them here.

The test will run until about Monday the 21st of June, at which point we'll be resetting the votes to close up to 5 while I review the responses here and dig into the data that we've been collecting.

Comment: Any way we can get some stats - e.g., for the trial so far, excluding instant close (moderator? high-rep users of a particular tag (I think I have that ability on [Electricity] which I discovered when I Close Voted and the effect was immediate) what % of questions were closed (i.e., with 3 votes) vs. for the previous 'x' days, what % were closed (5 votes) and what % languished with 3 or 4 votes that *would* have been closed if 3 votes were active?

Comment: In addition, it would be helpful to know how many aged away under 3 votes vs 5

Comment: I admit that I wasn't aware that the change was implemented. I also admit that I didn't notice a change even as a regular close voter, possibly because I operate in a three-vote situation on Stack Overflow already. I'll pay more attention.

Comment: Not likely to have close vote privilege anytime soon myself, I see the issue of 3 or 5  CVs depends on how patient reviewers are to the OPs willingness to modify or delete an off topic or poorly focused question.

Comment: Stats (please share them with the class) are going to be _far_ more meaningful than feelings. Feelings can change from day to day, and even from "before lunch" to "after lunch". I'd suggest that the fact that there have been a total of 5 comments (now) bears this out.

Comment: Now that it's been almost 3 months since you've asked this question (and there's been no further discussion), I'd say my _feeling_ is that there are still a _lot_ of questions, especially older ones, that probably _should_ be closed but aren't getting closed, even with only 3 votes necessary. (I also note that we still haven't seen any statistics on before v after close rates, aged out close votes, etc.)